# use define to assign a struct member to another member of the same struct

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
typedef struct{
               [..]
               type_t member1;
               type_t member2;
               [...]       

}structType_t
```

I want to assign member1 to member2. As this is a repeated operation I thought of putting the assignmet in a #define:

```
#define op (structType_t).member1=(structType_t).member2
```

However, this seems to be wrong how would the compiler know that it is the members of the same struct and I can't see a way of using it.
Any ideas?
I know I have other options such as macro or function but my question is this way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing such macros is never a good idea. It is probably not possible to write something better and more readable than `mystruct.member1 = mystruct.member2;`.

If you want to encapsulate this for whatever reason, use a function:

```
void structTypeMemberCopy (structType_t* obj)
{
  obj->member1 = obj->member2;
}
```

This is likely going to get inlined and replaced with the equivalent of `mystruct.member1 = mystruct.member2;` in the machine code.

And finally there is the *bad idea* macro, which can be made type safe:

```
#define structTypeCopy(obj) _Generic((obj), structType_t: (obj).member1 = (obj).member2)

...

structType_t mystruct = { ... };
structTypeCopy(mystruct);
```

Comment: I do not seem to understand how the last macro work and why you label it as type safe ?

Comment: You can add the inline keyword to insure it is inlined.

Comment: @Abyr The _Generic keyword was added in C11 and can compile-time check which type the variable `obj` passed to the macro got. If it is the correct type, in this case something with type `structType_t`, it will run the code `(obj).member1 = (obj).member2`. If it is the wrong type, you get a compiler error.

Comment: @MeherKhiari That's mostly obsolete style programming though. Nowadays compilers are better than programmers at determining what should be inlined. For example, if the programmer uses `inline` excessively, you might end up with an unnecessary large program size.

Answer (score -1):

You need to define the macro like this:

```
#define a(T1) T1.n1 = T1.n2
```

the macro `a` receive one parameter `T1` and does the asignement.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

#define a(T1) T1.n1 = T1.n2

typedef struct {
    int n1;
    int n2;
} estructure;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    estructure test;

    test.n1 = 1;
    test.n2 = 2;

    a(test);

    std::cout << test.n1 << " " << test.n2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is tagged C. And that macro is very dangerous because it lacks parenthesis. And it isn't typesafe if you have several structs with same member names.